# Object oriented Operations PHP

Tags: php, calculator

```
<?php
// define class
class Calculator {

  //class variables:
  var $sum;
  var $dif;
  var $multi;
  var $div;


  //Class member functions or methods:
  function add($arr) {
    $this->sum=array_sum($arr);
  }

  function substract($arr){
    for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
      $dif=$dif - $arr[$i+1];
      $this->dif=dif-arr[$i];
    }
  }

  function multiply($arr) {
    $this->multi=$number1 * $number2;
  }

  function devide($arr) {
    $this->div=$number1/$number2;
  }
}


$txtfield = $_POST['number1'];
$arr = explode(' ',trim($txtfield));


//Create a class instance:
$calc = new Calculator();

//Call class methods:
$calc->add($arr); 
$calc->substract($arr); 
$calc->multiply($arr); 
$calc->devide($num1,$num2);

//Display output:
echo "Sum=".$calc->sum." <br>"; 
echo "Difference =".$calc->dif." <br>"; 
echo "Multilpication=".$calc->multi." <br>"; 
echo "Division=".$calc->div."<br>";

?>
```

Why doesn't my code display the correct value? I tried entering 3 values and it still won't return the right results. It seems it doesn't perform the operations well.

This is the test URL
http://modkoredesigns.com/phpexam/

I tried entering 2 2 2 on the textbox and it doesn't display the answer

Comment: You are mixing multiple ideas here. If you 1) correct the indentation levels in your code, 2) separate class definition from the code that uses it (and reads values from `$_POST`), I may help you.

Comment: you might find this lecture useful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc

Answer (score 2):

First, you got an error on that line :

```
$this->dif=dif-arr[$i];
```

you're missing two `$`

Then, where `$number1` and `$number2` come from ? (in both `multiply()` and `devide()`)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the complete wrong variables in the functions. Where do you get $number1 or $number2 from in the multiply function?
Besides the ugly formatting, which makes reading your code a real pain, there are more serious weaknesses in your code.
Why do you store the values in the class when you give them as parameter to each function anyways?